# Offset for content of the collection view cells

Tags: swift, collectionview

How to make content offset of collection view cell. Code below what do I have but It doesn't work for some reason:

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "pCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1")!

    cell.offset(offset: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -30.0))

    return cell
  }
```

My cell class code:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
  var image: UIImage = UIImage() {
    didSet{
      self.imageView.image = image
    }
  }

  func offset(offset: CGPoint) {
    self.imageView.frame = self.imageView.bounds.offsetBy(dx: offset.x, dy: offset.y)
  }
}
```

I just can't see any offset when cells are displayed. What I do wrong, guys?

Comment: Unless it is something specific to your subclass, `UICollectionViewCell` has no property called `offset`.

Comment: @Wes yes I updated my question.

Comment: Do you have any constraints applied to `imageView`?

Comment: @Wes you were right! I added constraints via IB and forgot about it! Waiting for your answer to accept it. Really thank you!

Comment: No problem, thanks! @wm.p1us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have any IB Constraints enabled on `imageView`, they will keep you from updating the frame.